# MYSQL Count query not working

Tags: mysql

Please help me why this query is not working. and How can I get the result? please help me.

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT ( select count('*') from `lostpets` where `lostpets`.`type` = 'Lost' ) as lost
     , ( select count('*') from `lostpets` where `lostpets`.`type` = 'Found' ) as found
     ,  
  FROM `lostpets`;
```

Comment: Always describe what does not work, do not simply write that it does not work a leave it to us to figure it out.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, it's because you need to remove the `,` after the second select: `...'Found') as found,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subqueries return the counts, therefore you do not need the `from` clause in the outer query and you do not need the single quotes around the `*`:

```
SELECT (select count(*) from `lostpets` where `lostpets`.`type` = 'Lost') as lost, 
      (select count(*) from `lostpets` where `lostpets`.`type` = 'Found') as found
```

Alternatively, you can use conditional counting and do this without subqueries:

```
SELECT count(if(`type` = 'Lost',1,null)) as lost,
       count(if(`type` = 'Found',1,null)) as found 
FROM `lostpets`
```

Comment: or just SUM(x='a')

Comment: @Strawberry or that